# How to save the renamed file using os python

Tags: python, save, file-rename

I am generating multiple pdf of the webpages , so each time the pdf file is generated I want to rename it and save that particular file. But my code renames the files as they are generated but removes the earlier file.
Below is my script:

```
os.chdir(new_path)
    files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(new_path))
    files = [os.path.join(new_path, f) for f in files] # add path to each file
    files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
    newest_file = files[-1]
    # os.path.join(new_path,search + str(photoid) + str(seaid_destination) + ".pdf",newest_file)
    os.rename(newest_file, search + str(photoid) + str(seaid_destination) + ".pdf")
```

It renames it correctly but it removes the earlier files to so how to save this renamed file. I tried `os.path.join` but the files are not saved.
The file to be saved is `newest_file`
Intially the file generated is `Google.pdf` so I want to rename it as `1.pdf` and save this file in a particular folder.

Comment: You want to copy instead of renaming the file(s)?

Comment: i want to rename the files generated and save this renamed files.

Comment: or else save the files

Comment: Show us the files before and after you run the script and how it should be instead!

Comment: are you using same name for all the files or does it change based on each file?

Comment: @deadshot It changes for each file generated

Comment: you renamed `google.pdf` to `1.pdf` now what is the name of the deleted file? are you saving all the files in same folder?

Comment: yes all the files in the same folder the above is just an example I have to rename and save 10 pdfs generated.

Comment: @deadshot So only the latest file ex 10.pdf remains the earlier 1.pdf~9.pdf are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In most operating system, renaming files or directories means moving them to another location. That's why *nix OSes uses `mv` (move) command.

In your case, if you want your original file remains, instead of renaming them you can copy them to new directory with new name.

Example of copying file using [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) modul:

```py
import shutil

shutil.copyfile('originalfile.pdf', 'newfile.pdf')
```

Comment: But I want to rename it and then move it